# Compare Xsl Variable

Tags: xslt-2.0

My Xsl code is like this  , I could not  enter inside when condition even isFlag is true,

```
<xsl:variable name="isFlag" select="java:isCustomerUnique($samledata)"/>     </xsl:variable>
         <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$isFlag = 'true'">
                  <uniqueData><xsl:value-of select="$uniqueData"/></uniqueData>
                  <isUnique><xsl:value-of select="$isUnique"/></isUnique>
```

**I could not check the condition if the condition is**

```
<xsl:when test="$isFlag = 'true'">
```

**It is working fine ,  if I change like this**

```
<xsl:when test="'true'= 'true'">
```

Comment: You code is getting lost, make sure your format your code snippets as code.

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion is, that the variable `$isFlag` is not `'true'`.

To debug the document processing just add the following line before `xsl:choose` to get the actual value of `$isFlag`:

```
<xsl:message terminate="no">The value of $isFlag is "<xsl:value-of select="$isFlag"/>"</xsl:message>
```

To stop the document processing you can set the attribute `terminate` to `yes`.